# Class not being update in DOM, handler not working properly

Tags: php, jquery

So, I am unsure if this is the right approach, but I hear that using the inline `onclick` handler as opposed to jquery handlers is not a good idea.

I have a dashboard of users, with a button to block/unblock the users. Here's the approach I am using to block them:

```
<script>
    $('.fa-unlock-alt').parent().on('click', function () {
        var $button = $(this)
        var id = $button.attr('id').slice(12);
        console.log($(this));


        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Websites/TimeTracking/Resources/PHP/Users/blockUser.php',
            data: {idUser: id, status: 'Inactivo'},
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == "Exito") {
                    alert("El acceso del usuario ha sido bloqueado!");
                    $button.find('i').toggleClass('fa-unlock-alt fa-lock');
                    $button.removeClass('btn-outline-success').addClass('btn-outline-danger');
                }
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (exception) {
                alert("No se pudo bloquear el acceso!");
                console.log(exception);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

I have a similar function, but it looks for `.fa-lock` instead of `fa-unlock-alt`, it does similar actions, but to unlock instead of locking.

Once the DOM loads, the first time you click the button it works properly, ajax call is made successfully, my database is updated accordingly, and the classes are changed as supposed, but whenever I try to click it again, it won't work.

A quick debugging showed me that even when the browser is displaying the colors and shapes I want, the DOM has actually the default value registered on the element's properties.

Is there a different approach I should be taking?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest you use (closest)[https://api.jquery.com/closest/] instead of the parent, but.. how? easy, put a class or just search for the parent tag name and you'll be sure that you're listening to the correct tag.

By the way, May ask you if you're using the  ``ready`` function?

Comment: Not using the `ready` function. Where exactly should I?

Comment: If you click the button to lock a user, why would you click it again. Are you re-locking somoene?

Comment: @chiliNUT The idea is that when you lock it, it becomes an 'unlock' button. But, while the appearance of the button changes to the 'unlock' properties, it is still registered on the DOM with the 'lock' properties.

Comment: @chiliNUT, check this out https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Firstly you need to put it inside the ready function, because you need to wait till all the dom is done.

Comment: @IdirOuhabMeskine why did you flag me it's not my question

Comment: @Lalo gotcha. If the same button is going to have alternating behavior, I'm guessing your issue is the on click code you have for the un lock handler, is never registered, because when it runs on page load, it has no unlock buttons to look for. then later when the page loads, you lock someone, and it turns into an unlock button, but since that unlock button didn't exist when the unlock event was registered, it never got the event. so I would suggest a single on click event, applied to all buttons, with an if block that says do one thing if it's an un-locker, do another if it's a locker.

Comment: Yes indeed, precisely what vasil indicated. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should register the click handler on the parent element ([delegate](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)). Something like

```
$('.parent-element-selector-here').on('click', '.fa-unlock-alt, .fa-lock', function () {

    var $button = $(this);

    if ($button.hasClass('fa-unlock-alt')) {

        // do this

    } else {

        // do that 

    }

});
```

Comment: Let me give it a go, I'll give you the feedback on this real quick.

Comment: I tried it exactly like this, but it wouldn't even recognize the click on the button

Comment: Something is not exactly like this, here it is working: https://jsfiddle.net/57uuxfyc/

Comment: Spot on! You were absolutely right. I missed a period to indicate a class. It is working wonders now! Thanks!